# Creating value type that raises exception on reading

Tags: python

How do I create a value type that raises an exception when read?

For example:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

Missing = ...


@dataclass
class A:
    a: int = field(default=None)  # <- value can be None
    b: int = field(default=Missing)  # <- can be Missing until you try to access it

    def print(self):
        for i in [self.a, self.b]:
            print(i)  # <- raises ValueError if i is Missing
```

Comment: That's not possible. What problem are hoping to solve by having such a type?

Comment: Saving object attributes to a dict. If some attribute is None, it doesn't get written to the dict, but if it's Missing, error is raised, indicating that attribute must be assigned before writing. @mkrieger1

Comment: Why do you not just specify no default value for the field?

Comment: Some attributes are required to have a certain value, without default. But it may not be known at object initialization.
So for example, I create object of a class, do some computations and after that assign that value. In this way variable is required to have a value, but it can be delayed. @mkrieger1

Comment: Okay. Then you have to explicitly check if a value is missing when accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, it seems there is always a way for anything :-)

It appears you can solve this by a clever use of a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) value as a dataclass field, as illustrated below. I would also read more on the section on [Validators](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#complete-practical-example) to understand a little bit more about how descriptors work.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


# create `_MissingType` class
_MissingType = type('_MissingType', (), {'__bool__': lambda self: False})

# create a singleton for that class
Missing = _MissingType()


class MissingValidator:
    __slots__ = ('default', 'private_name')

    # You may or may not want a default value
    def __init__(self, default=Missing):
        self.default = default

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.private_name = '_' + name

    # override __get__() to return a default value if one is not passed in to __init__()
    def __get__(self, obj, obj_type=None):
        try:
            value = getattr(obj, self.private_name)

            if value is Missing:
                cls_name = obj_type.__qualname__
                public_name = self.private_name.lstrip('_')
                raise ValueError(f'Missing value for field `{public_name}` in class `{cls_name}`')

            return value

        except AttributeError:
            return self.default

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        setattr(obj, self.private_name, value)


@dataclass
class A:
    a: int = None  # <- value can be None
    b: int = MissingValidator()  # <- can be Missing until you try to access it

    def print(self):
        for i in [self.a, self.b]:
            print(i)  # <- raises ValueError if i is Missing


A(b=3).print()
# None
# 3

A(a=42).print()
# raises:
#   ValueError: Missing value for field `b` in class `A`
```